# Update XML node value after calculation

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having XML like as follows

```
<Components>
  <Component>
    <Name>Comp1</Name>
    <Baseline>Comp1_2.1.0.20.2824</Baseline>
    <KLOC>0</KLOC>
    <IsCount>True</IsCount>
    </Component>
  <Component>
    <Name>Comp2</Name>
    <Baseline>Comp2_2_7_2012.3171</Baseline>
    <KLOC>0</KLOC>
    <IsCount>True</IsCount>
  </Component>
</Components>
```

I am having log files names such as Comp1.log, Comp2.log and etc.

Comp1 code count should goes to KLOC tag of Component name Comp1.

Following is the logic to find the fetch code count. Our code count will be available in log file like follows.

> Total Lines (version 2)        : 1084

I will terminate strings except the version number using following logic.

```
    $Files=Get-ChildItem -Path  $CCountFolder -Recurse
    $Totallinesver2+= Get-ChildItem -Path $CCountFolder -Recurse | Foreach { Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-string -simplematch "Total Lines (version 2)" }

        Foreach ( $line in $Totallinesver2) { $Count+= ($line -replace "Total Lines \(version 2\)        : ","" )}
        $count
Foreach ($file in $Files) { $file.Name }
```

Now I wanted to store KLOC in the respective component KLOC tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a little XPath you can get a handle to the text() node and set it's value.

**Update**: To make your Xpath query dynamic based on the names of the files your parsing you can use the `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method. This will work as long as the name of the file matches up to the component name in your XML. Add your code to retrieve the `$count` variable inside the `foreach` loop.

```
$doc = [xml] (Get-Content "C:\InputFile.xml")
$compFiles = 'Comp1.log', 'Comp2.log'

foreach ($file in $compFiles) {

    # Get $count from $file here...

    $compName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $xpath = "//Component[Name='${compName}']/KLOC/text()"
    $node = $doc.SelectSingleNode($xpath)
    $node.Value = $count
}

$doc.Save("C:\Output.xml")
```

Comment: I have added some more clarity to question dude. If possible help me out

Comment: @Samselvaprabu I updated my answer based on your added requirements.